# Euclidean norm of column difference

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, norm

I want to have the euclidean norm of the difference for every two columns in a matrix. So that for example `Column1-Column3` has its euclidean norm in the final matrix at `(1,3)` and `(3,1)`. I already have a code, but I would like to ask if there is a simpler and especially faster way to get this kind of a matrix.

```
A = rand(4)
B=zeros(size(A));
for i = 2:size(A,1)
   diffCol = A - [A(:,i:end),A(:,1:i-1)];
   normsCol= sqrt(sum(diffCol.^2, 1));
   B=B+diag(normsCol(1:end-i+1),i-1);
end
B = B + B'
```

Example for a random 4x4 Matrix:

[image]

Comment: Transpose the input array to feed to the solution code(s) from the linked question and at the end square-root the output to get the desired output here.

Comment: Great, works really fine and is much faster than my code.